# What is incorrect in my way for getting Fourier transform of step function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, step-function

Today I tried to get Fourier transform of `step function` ($u(t)$). But I got a result which seems is not correct. I want to know what is incorrect in my work?

With attention to this relation:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{u(t)=\frac{1}{2}[1+sgn(t)]}
\end{align}
we know that:
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{F}(u(t))=\left (\pi\delta(\omega) + \frac{1}{j\omega}\right )
\end{align}

Today I tried to experience another way. Suppose:

$$
\begin{align}
g(t) = 
    \begin{cases}
        e^{-at} & \text{for } t > 0\\
        0       & \text{otherwise }
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

So:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{F}(g(t)) = &\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} e^{-i\omega t}\, dt\\
        &=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(a+i\omega) t}\, dt\\
        &=\big[
            \frac{e^{-(a+i\omega) t}}{-(a+i\omega)}
            \big]_{0}^{\infty}\\
        &=\frac{1}{a+i\omega}
\end{align*}
$$

It is obvious that $\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+}g(t)= u(t)$. Thus:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{F}(u(t)) &= \mathfrak{F}(\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+}g(t))\\
&=\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+}(\mathfrak{F}(g(t))\\
&=\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+}(\frac{1}{a+i\omega})\\
&=\frac{1}{i\omega}
\end{align} 
$$
What is incorrect in my work?

Comment: The integral of the limit is not always the limit of the integral.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, but when it is correct? I saw that in getting Fourier transform of `sgn` function.

Comment: You need to prove it is correct to switch the limit and integral. Here, of course, the only place where it is incorrect is when $\omega=0.$

Comment: But the real problem is that $1/(a+wi)$ does not converge to anything when $\omega=0.$

Comment: To add to the comment posted by @Gonçalo , the Fourier transform is a distribution on the Schwartz space $\mathbb{S}$ of functions.   The limit $\lim_{a\to 0^+}\left(\frac1{a+i\omega}\right)$ is a distributional limit, such that for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$, we have $$\lim_{a\to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(\omega)}{a+i\omega}\,d\omega=\pi \phi(0)+\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(\omega)}{i\omega}\,d\omega$$

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you for your time. Can you add your comment as an answer? So I can accept it and it may be more useful for other users than a comment. Also I think it is better to add more details about why $\cal{P}\frac{1}{\omega} = \frac{1}{\omega}$?